# How best to use Eign to filter & resize an image?

Tags: signal-processing, eigen

I have an image, a 2D array of uint8_ts.  I want to resize the image using a separable filter.  Consider shrinking the width first.  Because original & target sizes are unrelated, we'll use a different set of coefficients for every destination pixel.  For a particular in & out size, for all y, we might have:

```
out(500, y) = in(673, y) * 12 + in(674, y) * 63 + in(675, y) * 25
out(501, y) =                   in(674, y) * 27 + in(675, y) * 58 + in(676, y) * 15
```

How can I use Eigen to speed this up, e.g. vectorize it for me?
This can be expressed as a matrix multiply with a sparse matrix, of dimension in_width * out_width, where in each row, only 3 out of the in_width values are non-zero.  In the actual use case, 4 to 8 will typically be non-zero.  But those non-zero values will be contiguous, and it would be nice to use SSE or whatever to make it fast.

Note that the source matrix has 8 bit scalars.  The final result, after scaling both width & height will be 8 bits as well.  It might be nice for the intermediate matrix (image) and filter to be higher precision, say 16 bits.  But even if they're 8 bits, when multiplying, we'll need to take the most significant bits of the product, not the least significant.

Is this too far out of with Eigen can do?  This sort of convolution, with a kernel that's different at every pixel (only because the output size isn't an integral multiple of the input size), seems common enough.

Comment: Answering this is way out of my comfort zone, but, try one question at at time. This is **not** a C++ question in any shape or form. There are math and DSP foras too, like [Signal Processing @ Stack Exchange](https://dsp.stackexchange.com).

Comment: For image operations better use a library like OpenCV

Comment: @chtz I looked at OpenCV, it can't do this at all.  It doesn't support low level operations like this.  It has a filter2d, which can only map from one image to another of the same size, and takes a fixed set of coefficients.  And it has a resize method, but you have to select from a list of pre-defined kernels, which don't include Mitchell.